# Change Geometry of TTK Frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

So I have an App/TTK.Frame class, and I wish to change it once my program starts so that I can change the way it looks and turn it into a "Status: xxxx" kind of thing at the top of the screen.

However, I can't seem to be able to edit the geometry because this is a ttk.frame class and thus doing root.geometry('100x100') does nothing.

```
class App(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self)

        # Make the app responsive
        for index in [0, 1, 2]:
            self.columnconfigure(index=index, weight=1)
            self.rowconfigure(index=index, weight=1)


        # Create control variables
        self.barbs = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
        self.buildings = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
        self.troops = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
        self.exploration = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
        self.gather = tk.StringVar()

        # Create widgets :)
        self.setup_widgets()

    def setup_widgets(self):
        #### Irrelevant code before this
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.widgets_frame, text="Button", command=self.startbtn2)
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")
    
    def startbtn2(self):
        self.changewindow()
        #### Irrelevant code after this

    def changewindow(self):
        self.widgets_frame.destroy()
        self.check_frame.destroy()
        root.geometry('100x100')
```

Also thought about doing it a different way, instead of destroying all the widgets and changing the geometry of the current window, I can just open a new one once the button is clicked / startbtn2 function starts, however, I need to call root.lift() on a loop so that the window always stays at the top of all other windows, and I think the only way to do so is if that's the main window, not a newly created one.

Comment: What is your exact intention? I feel like I do not get your question right.

Comment: @Thingamabobs So my end result that I wish to get is basically, once I click the button to start the function "startbtn2" I will get a window at the top of the screen that stays on top of all other windows, however, for that I need to call root.lift() in a loop which can only be done on the main frame if I recall correctly so my intention was to destroy all the widgets on my main frame once the button was clicked, change the size(geometry) and then just change the main frame to a small window saying "Status: xxxx"

Comment: every *window* can have the topmost attribute and you set it like this `window.attributes('-topmost', True)`

Comment: @Thingamabobs Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for! That makes everything so much easier

Comment: this sounds like how python normally works. when a function is done it returns to the point where it started and runs the next line. You should go for some tutorials that explains you the basics.